# Ext.plugin.ListPaging - common 'load more...' issue

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm dealing with the following problem, I got the below code:

**VIEW:**

```
Ext.define('aBMin.view.Email', {
extend : 'Ext.Panel',
alias : 'widget.email-panel',
config : {
    layout : "fit",
    items : [{
        xtype : 'toolbar',
        ui : 'light',
        layout : 'hbox',            
        docked : 'top',
        items : [{
            xtype : 'searchfield',
            name : 'emailsearch',
            width: '45%',
            flex : 1
        }, {
            xtype : 'selectfield',
            flex : 2,   
            name : 'emailassign',
            value : 'unassigned',
            options : [{
                text : 'All',
                value : 'all'
            }, {
                text : 'Assigned',
                value : 'assigned'
            }, {
                text : 'Unassigned',
                value : 'unassigned'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        xtype : 'list',
        action : 'readEmail',
        itemTpl : '<tpl for="."><div class="list-pos-row"><div class="list-pos-col">{emailsubject}</div></div><div class="list-pos-row"><div class="list-pos-col list-email-date">{emaildate}</div></div><div class="list-pos-row"><div class="list-pos-col list-email-from">{emailfrom}</div></div></tpl>',
        itemSelector : 'div.contact',
        emptyText : 'No data found.',
        onItemDisclosure : true,
        store : 'Email',
        plugins : [{
            xclass : 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging : true,
            noMoreRecordsText: 'No More Records'
        }],
    }]
}
});
```

**STORE:**

```
Ext.define('aBMin.store.Email', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
requires : ['aBMin.model.Email'],
config : {
    autoLoad : true,
    model : 'aBMin.model.Email',
    remoteFilter : true,
    proxy : {
        type : 'direct',
        extraParams : {
            filter : 'unassigned'
        },
        directFn : ClientemailTable.getListMobile,
        config : {
            paramsAsHash : true,
            reader : {
                type : 'json',
                rootProperty : 'records'
                ,totalCount: 'totalCount'   
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

**MODEL**

```
Ext.define('aBMin.model.Email', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
config : {
    fields : [{
        name : 'clientemailid',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'clientid',
        type : 'int'
    },{
        name : 'emailsubject',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'emailfrom',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'emailbody',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'supportstaffid',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'ticketid',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'emaildate',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'isassigned',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'newemailnote',
        type : 'string'
    }],
    idProperty : 'clientemailid',
    proxy : {
        type : 'direct',
        reader : {
            type : 'json'
        },
        api : {
            read : Clientemail.readMobile,
            update : Clientemail.updateMobile
        }
    }
}
});
```

now... my service returns the following JSON response:

[image]

it's returned when the app send for ex. a request with a below like params:

[image]

and still... the 'load more', won't disapear.

[image]

So I guess what I'm trying to achieve is to get rid the 'load more...' button when the store is fully loaded. I've read few other topics on StackOverflow but didn't solve the thing.

Any comments / hins appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key should be totalProperty in reader configuration, not totalCount.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader

Comment: Yes, thank You - I've resolved it earlier but for others that will deal with the similar problem it'll be helpful :)